# Javascript Input Field Validation (Number only)

Tags: javascript

I want to make my input element accept only number. I want to validate it real time and turn the color of label into red when the input is not equal to 10 digit.

Help please on my js condition. Thanks.

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    document.getElementById("lbltest").style.color = "red"
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("lbltest").style.color = "green"
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<label id="lbltest">Test</label>
<input name="txtTry" type="text" pattern=".{10,}"
       minlength="10" maxlength="10"
       onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
```

Comment: Wouldn't `<input type="number">` be part of this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Comment: Why not use `type="number"` for a start...

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to test if the given input is numeric?

Comment: You said what you want but didn't explain what is wrong with the code you posted. You haven't explained what specific issue you are having. You haven't explained what is confusing you.

Comment: Hi guys. Im sorry. But I explain exactly what i need to do on my post.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var input=document.getElementById('input'),
    label=document.getElementById('lbltest');

input.oninput=function(){
  var value=this.value;
  var isnum = /^\d+$/.test(value);
  if(isnum && value.length===10){
    label.style.color="green";
  }else{
      label.style.color="red";
  }
      
  }
```

```html
<label id="lbltest">Test </label>
<input id="input" name="txtTry" type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: hi. thank you so much. this is working perfectly but when i click submit button and i input 10 character, it still accept it and submitted. can we try to make it accept only number just like my previous code?

Answer (score 1):

Since using jQuery makes it a bit easier to handle events, I've integrated the library to solve the scenario. I've kept the element attributes which you can use or remove on your own demand.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.validate').on('input', function(event) {
    var $element = $(this);
    var valid = true;
    if ($element.attr('pattern')) {
      var pattern = new RegExp($element.attr('pattern'));
      valid = valid && pattern.test($element.val());
    }
    if ($element.attr('minlength')) {
      value = valid && $element.val().length >= $element.attr('minlength');
    }
    if ($element.attr('maxlength')) {
      value = valid && $element.val().length <= $element.attr('maxlength');
    }
    if (!valid) {
      $element.addClass('validation-error');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('validation-error');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<style>
.validation-error { border: 1px red solid; background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25); }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="lbltest">Test </label>
<input id="input" class="validate"
       name="txtTry" type="text"
       minlength="10" maxlength="10"
       pattern="^\d{10}$">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
function isNumberKey(evt){
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode 
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
    document.getElementById("lbltest").style.color="red"
    return false; 
  }
  else{
    if (document.getElementById("txtTry").value.length < 10){
      document.getElementById("lbltest").style.color="red"
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("lbltest").style.color="green"
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<label id="lbltest">Test </label>
<input name="txtTry" id="txtTry" type="text" pattern=".{10,}" minlength="10" maxlength="10" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event)">
```

Comment: thanks mate! this is working perfectly! exactly as what i need to do! :)

Comment: hi, another thing. when i try your code and when the field is null it label turns red. i want Label to retain color black when it is empty value.

Comment: you can do that by adding another condition ("if(document.getElementById("txtTry").value.length == 1)") inside the if block where the length of the input is being counted. but i think doing so is not logically valid.

Comment: i keep getting red color when the field is empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Try use package [input-only-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/input-only-numbers).

```js
/**
 * Function exec after susses fill input fields
 * 
 * @param {Event} element 
 */
function callback(element) {
    console.log('%cValid value: ' + element.target.value, 'color: green; font-size: 2rem;');
}
 
let inputOnlyNumbers = new InputOnlyNumbers({
    className: 'input-only-numbers',
    callback: callback
});
 
inputOnlyNumbers.init();
```

```css
.success {
  color: #00ff00;
}

.fail {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/input-only-numbers@1.0.6/dist/index.js"></script>
<label id="lbltest">Test</label>
<input 
  class="input-only-numbers"
  name="txtTry"
  data-limit="10"
  data-valid="success"
  data-invalid="fail"
  type="text" 
>
```